# Find the required angle of rotation to move from point A to point B

Tags: c#, math

I want to make a bot that will walk along points from two coordinates (X and Y), I have the coordinates of the character, his rotation angle (1-180 / (- 1) - (-180)), and the required point where he is should get there. How do I know if the angle of rotation is necessary for the person to look directly at the point?

I have been sitting with this for a long time, and my head refuses to think at all, I tried to solve this by creating an angle between the `radius vector`, but nothing came of it.

```
  public static double GetRotation(Point Destination)
    {
          double cos = Destination.Y / Math.Sqrt(Destination.X * Destination.X + Destination.Y * Destination.Y);
          double angle = Math.Acos(cos);
        return angle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to this problem, I would suggest generally using tan rather than cos due to the fact to get the angle between two point (X and y), the difference in the points provide the opposite and adjacent sides of the triangle for the calculation, rather than adjacent and hypotenuse.

If the player is at position X,Y, and the new position to walk to is X2,Y2, the equation to calculate the relative angle between them should be tan-1((Y2-Y)/(X2-X)) with regards to the X plane.

I think the below implementation should work for your example (though you may need to subtract the current player angle the player is facing to get the difference):

```
public static double GetRotation(Point source, Point Destination)
    {
          double tan = (Destination.Y - source.Y) / (Destination.X -source.X);
          double angle = Math.Atan(tan) * (180/Math.PI) // Converts to degrees from radians
        return angle;
    }
```

Apologies for the formatting, am currently on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
dx = Destination.X - Person.X;
dy = Destination.Y - Person.Y;
directionangle = Math.Atan2(dy, dx); // in radians!
degrees = directionangle * 180 / Math.PI;
```